# Always show red border color in DatePicker from @mui-x-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, formik

Hi folks I'm new in React. In my project I've used DatePicker component from material ui. I used this with formik and Yup. But for some reason my Date field always showing red during page initial loading without any clicking of button and touch of field.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useField } from 'formik'
import { Grid, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

function DatePickerField(props) {
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(props)
  const { touched, error } = meta
  const { setValue } = helper
  const isError = touched && error
  const { value } = field
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      const date = new Date(value)
      setSelectedDate(date)
    }
  }, [value])

  function _onChange(date) {
    if (date) {
      setSelectedDate(date)
      const ISODateString = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
      setValue(ISODateString)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          disablePast
          error={false}
          {...field}
          {...props}
          value={dayjs(selectedDate)}
          onChange={_onChange}
        />
        {isError && <FormHelperText error>{error}</FormHelperText>}
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default DatePickerField
```